# Giving an executable more permissions than running user

Tags: c++, linux, beagleboneblack

I have a small C++ app to turn on and off lights for a BeagleBone Black board that runs on Debian 9.2.

It does this by updating text files.

```
// Turn light on
fs.open("/sys/class/leds/beaglebone:green:usr0", std::fstream::out);
fs << "1";
fs.close();
```

If I run the program as a standard user it runs without error but none of the lights change.

If I run the program with `sudo` everything works fine and the lights work. 
I'm guessing it's because those files needs higher access.

I'm not super familiar with Linux permissions but is there a way to allow your program access to the files where a user could not?

Comment: I think 20 years ago you could give the binary super-user flag, but that's very wrong solution, not even sure if it still works, or it would clash with some security policy. Rather check the affected beaglebone files, if they belong to certain group and have group rights for write enabled, then add that group to your user (which does run the binary). Anyway, I'm just linux user, not admin, so I may mixed up something about how groups work. Either way, this is purely about *nix permissions, nothing to do with C++ or programming.

Comment: If you need elevated permission to write to a file you have to run the program with elevated permissions.  There is just no way around that.  What you can (and should) do however, is drop the privileges until you need to actually perform tasks with elevated privileges using [setuid](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setuid-Program-Example.html).

Comment: Makes sense and thank you both. I'm a complete Linux noob and come from 25+ years of MS stack development so it's tough to wrap my head around some of the concepts :)

Comment: @Ped7g: The setuid flag is still valid in Unix and Unlx like systems. `su` and `sudo` are nothing more than programs owned by root with that special bit set, no further black magic is involved. Simply it is advised to avoid that because it used to be the source of many security problems. Basile's answer explains it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read *carefully* about [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) and about [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) (and [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) which is how programs are started). But be careful about [vulnerabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulnerability_(computing)).

Read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://richard.esplins.org/static/downloads/linux_book.pdf) (freely downloadable, but a bit old) or some newer book about Linux programming. Read [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html) and [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

You could also read [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) (freely downloadable) to learn more about OSes in general.

You could make your executable setuid (with `chmod u+s` after the appropriate `chown`) and call *with care* [setreuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setreuid.2.html) at appropriate places. That is how programs like `sudo` or `su` works (all of them are setuid). Sometimes you can just use group permissions (so setgid only).

But be cautious, a bug in such a program can open a huge security hole. So it is wise to keep setuid programs very small and have their code reviewed by other eyes. A possible approach is to code a very small setuid executable doing your weird things (e.g. only flashing the leds) and communicating (e.g. with [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)-s or other forms of [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)) with a larger and bigger ordinary program (e.g. providing a GUI).

Perhaps you can configure your system by creating a group `led` and giving group write permissions to `/sys/class/leds/beaglebone:green:usr0` and use only setgid techniques.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to approach this and it depends a lot on the larger setting which one is more suitable. 
One way is to change the permissions of that particular file (not sure if sysfs allows that).

Another is to add the user who will be running this to a group that has write access to the file.

Yet another is the already mentioned setting of the so called setuid bit and changing ownership of the executable to root or a user with write access to that file. This usually has deeper security implications.

Also using sudo or su to execute the file is a valid approach. To limit security exposure you can allow for this particular command in sudoers.

A variation on one of the above is to run a persistent process listening for commands from a less privileged process.

As said, a lot depends on how this fits into the larger setting. Also to avoid opening a security hole implications need to be considered.